# Bloqueio(reserva) de uma linha auto incremento no mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Desenvolvi um importador de dados *CSV* para a minha base `mysql`.
O Recurso está funcionando corretamente, porém acredito que deve ter uma forma melhor de implementar a seguinte lógica.

No arquivo *CSV* dependendo ou não pode ser que ocorra 2 inserts(mestre-detalhe) e a unica forma que tenho no momento de controla-los é através de sua *PK* auto-incremento.

O que eu faço - Realizo um insert, se existir tal informação do detalhe, eu recupero o ultimo `insert (select max(id) table`, ou com a função `LAST_INSERT_ID()` e salva na minha tbl de detalhe a informação recuperada.

Como o meu serviço é online, e outras pessoas podem realizar o mesmo procedimento de importação, pode ser que ocorra o evento do *insert* no mesmo time e minha operação deixa de ser confiável.

Uma forma que pensei, e estou pesquisando é, como o `mysql` já sabe qual o próximo índice, eu de alguma forma reservar e bloquear este índice e fazer o meu procedimento, caso ocorra algo comitantemente ele prossiga com a próxima linha.

Alguém já trabalhou com este problema?

Comment: Você pode criar um lock na table durante o INSERT, assim as rotinas paralelas teriam que aguardar a anterior ser concluida.

Comment: Obrigado gmsantos.

Comment: Também achei uma alternativa bacana e que talvéz também me ajude. Vou deixar aqui SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `database` LIKE 'table'